# Line coverage 100% for Junit test

Tags: java, junit

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = null;
try
{
    builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
}
catch (ParserConfigurationException e)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try
{
    doc = builder.parse(entity.getContent());
}
catch (IllegalStateException e)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (SAXException e)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I am using the dom to parse the xml file to string. How to write a unit test to catch 100% line coverage to the expection. i am using eachmock.

Comment: Generally speaking, it is a waste of time to try to achieve 100% coverage for unit tests.

Comment: Two questions (1) What is eachmock?  (2) Why do you want 100 percent line coverage?

Comment: typos, it is easymock?   it is requirement for the task...

Comment: No, 100% line coverage is never a requirement for any task.  If this is what you are aiming for, then you are going to end up wasting an awful lot of your time, and therefore of your employer's money.  You should aim to have tests that cover 100% of the requirements of your class.  Coverage of lines is not the right thing to count.

Answer (score 1):

You don't, because it's pointless.

If you have a manager who doesn't understand that, then here's how to test:

- `DocumentBuilderFactory` describes the mechanism used to configure a parser. By changing a system property, you can use your own (mock) class as a factory. And it can throw that exception.
- `SaxException` is thrown by malformed XML. Create some malformed XML and pass it to your code.
- `IllegalStateException` is thrown when your argument is `null`. So pass `null`

I should correct myself: it's not pointless. If you do succeed in getting 100% coverage, you'll discover that your exception handling should be fixed. As written, your code just keeps running (until it gets a NPE, that is) after an exception, which it shouldn't do.

Comment: Can you show me the implementation of mocking code about the above 3 exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

`IllegalStateException` will get thrown from a null URI.

`SAXException` will get thrown if any parser error occurs (such as an improperly formatted document).

`ParserConfigurationException` will only get thrown if the configurations you gave the factory prevent it from creating the object.

However, these exceptions don't really need to be tested since all you are doing is printing the stack trace. Getting 100% code coverage isn't always needed, especially in cases like this where you'd only be testing the known functionality of Java libraries.

If you have logic in your exception, you could test the logic by pulling it out into a method.

e.g.

```
public void printStackTrace(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is an easily testable method that does not require you to find a way to trigger the exception in a different part of your code.